# chain rule for differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:U \to V$ be (smooth) map, where $U,V \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ are open subsets. Let $X(t)\in U$, then I saw an equation like $$\frac d {dt} f(X(t)) = df(X(t))X'(t)$$

But I'm not understanding what does it mean by $df$? I saw pushforward, tangent space, total derivative, jacobian matrix, etc. in wikipedia, but there are too many general concepts.  Could someone explain it and give some book recommendation about differential geometry?

Comment: $df$ is the Jacobian of $f$, i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: @Tomás One minor detail: the Jacobian is a matrix while $df$ is a linear map. The Jacobian is the matrix of $df$ with respect to a local coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, you are right @FlybyNight. I am so used to identify these things, that I totally forgot this distinction.

Comment: What is $X$ in the first line of the question?